# "Undefined control sequence." when using autocite and biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biblatex-chicago

I've wrestled for days with this problem for days, and have looked at the forum for answers, but to no avail.

## I have in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquote}
\usepackage[notes,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

## For the bibliography output I have:

```
\printbibliography
```

## However, I keep getting this error:

> ```
> Package hypperref Warning: Return to get /pagelabels entry.
> (./main.bbl
> ./main.bbl:20: undefined control sequence.
> \blx@slist@name ->\cms @choose/global/
> l.20 \entry{*****}{article}{}
> ?
> ```

## When I click on "Go to error", it takes me to my main.bbl file,

\sortlist[entry]{\cms@choose/global/}

\entry{*****}{article}{}

```
\field{labeltitlesource}{title}

\field{sortinit}{2}

\field{sortinithash}{2}

\field{title}{XTITLEOFARTICLEX}

\field{journaltitle}{{XJOURNALNAMEX}}

\field{month}{08}

\field{year}{2010}
```

\endentry

I'd be grateful for any help. I apologise if my question has not been posted in proper format, this is my first ever question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by post a full MWE with bibliography (including the problematic part). Also try to delete auxiliary files and compile again (or run bibtex again and show its output).

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks. I've tried to delete the auxiliary files. Didn't work. (And Unless the auxiliary files are somewhere I don't know.) I'll add what I think you mean by the problematic part.

Comment: It seems that biblatex-chicago doesn't work currently (or none at all) with the backend bibtex. Remove backend=bibtex and change in your editor to biber.

Comment: It is a bug in biblatex-chicago. With the bibtex backend it uses `\cms@choose` before it is defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the tip. How do I change my editor to biber? How does the typesetting change? I'm sorry if my questions are a bit too rudimentary for people here. I'll add that this was working until a few days ago. This suddenly popped up.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Actually the problem is not only that the command is not defined but that is also not expanded. In any case I wouldn't use bibtex backend with biblatex-chicago.

Comment: This problem has been resolved by using biber. Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer. I think we can mark this conversation as resolved. No?

Comment: I added a short answer so that you can accept it and so remove the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-chicago` sets the sorting with

```
 \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{...,sorting=\cms@choose,...}
```

With `bibtex` as backend the command `\cms@choose` ends up unexpanded in the control-file (a special bib created by biblatex) and then also in the bbl.

When the `bbl` is read at the begin of document LaTeX chokes on the @ in the command name and gives an error. The error could be avoided by activating `\makeatletter` but this wouldn't resolve the problem that `bibtex` didn't get the correct sorting name.

With the biber backend there is no problem.

As a conclusion I would avoid the `bibtex` backend with `biblatex-chicago` and switch to `biber`. A link how to do this is [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations).

Comment: Nice suggestion...Thanks a lot...